# AngularJS nested loops - how do i get to not display an item when a condition fails in an inner ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say I have a nested loop like the code below

```
<div ng-repeat="m in masters">
      <h3> {{m.name}} </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">

       <a ng-if="m.url === i.url"> {{i.name}} </a>
   </div> </div>
```

How do I get to not have line 3 `<h3> ... </h3>` display the name when the condition 
`<a ng-if"..."> ... </a>` fails and return nothing.

Comment: I would suggest a custom filter for this. I can write you up an example if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

use a function to test whether the child condition exists -- so in your controller add a function like:

```
$scope.itemsHasUrl = function(url) {
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++) {
    if($scope.items[i].url === url) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

then in the template

```
<div ng-repeat="m in masters">
    <h3 ng-if"itemsHasUrl(m.url)"> {{m.name}} </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">

       <a ng-if="m.url === i.url"> {{i.name}} </a>
   </div> 
</div>
```

you may also want to look into [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) as you may be able to use the same function to limit the items checked in the interior loop, or using [angular-filters groupBy method](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) to avoid a double-loop at all.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in your controller to check if one of the `items` has the given url

```
$scope.checkUrl = function(url, items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].url == url) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

in your template

```
<h3 ng-if="checkUrl(m.url, items)"> {{m.name}} </h3>
```

Comment: There are no other changes in the template needed if I unterstand the question right

Comment: I guess I was assuming a 1:1 ratio between i.url and m.url, if that's the case, then the ng-repeat is unnecessary. However, if there can be multiple item urls that match the master url (which, the more I think about it, is probably the case), then this solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To entertain my original comment, and derelict's answer, here is a `.filter()` way of doing this.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="m in masters | checkUrl:items">
    <h3>{{m.name}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="i in items | checkUrl:m">
      <a>{{i.name}}</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter("checkUrl", function () {
  return function (items, checkValues) {
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      if (typeof(checkValues.url) === "string") {
        // single item check
        return item.url === checkValues.url;
      }
      // else multiple items check
      return checkValues.some(function (value) {
        return value.url === item.url; 
      });
    });
  };
})
.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) { 
  // controller code here ...
}
```